# UPDATE INNER JOIN no se ejecuta

Tags: mysql

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE invoice_detail
        INNER JOIN
    products ON invoice_detail.idt_productCode = products.prd_code 
SET 
    invoice_detail.idt_productId = products.prd_id;
```

Se trata de la migracion de una base de datos, en la base de datos de origen la relacion se hacia por medio del codigo del producto y en la base de datos destino se hace con el id del producto.

al tratar de ejecutar el `query` se queda `running...`, he esperado hasta 2 horas y 45 minutos y nada, las tablas tienen 400,000 registros la del detalle de factura y 18,000 registros la de productos.

Comment: Hola. Como sugerencia, procura siempre incluir en tus preguntas de SQL datos de prueba, el resultado esperado y lo que sale con tu consulta

Answer (score -1):

Una opción es hacer la consulta con límite de registros para que actualice parte de los registros en cada ejecución. Puedes probar primero con un límite bajo e ir aumentando en función de la capacidad de respuesta de la base de datos. Requiere ejecutar tantas veces como sea necesario hasta completar la actualización.

Adaptado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558958/5675636.

```
UPDATE invoice_detail i JOIN 
   ( 
     SELECT id.idt_productCode, pd.prd_code, pd.prd_id
     FROM invoice_detail id JOIN products pd
        ON id.idt_productCode = pd.prd_code
     ORDER BY pr.prd_id
     LIMIT 100
   ) p
ON i.idt_productCode = p.prd_code 
SET i.idt_productId = p.prd_id;
```

Comment: Pero y esto como mejora el problema? solo va a ser que termine en algunos puntos... pero no soluciona el problema final, al cual el usuario no puso nada como para poder resolverlo...

Comment: @gbianchi hacer el update por partes permite hacer el update que se está bloqueando por el elevado número de registros, y al ser un evento único que sólo es necesario hacer una vez por registro lo considero un posible modo de lograr el update. Seguro que hay otros, esto es sólo una posibilidad que puede funcionar.

Comment: @Carmen, el problema esta complicado... Si, intente ejecutar el ´query´, no solo por lotes, sino con un solo registro y se queda pegado en ´Running... ´ intente vaciar (´TRUNCATE´) la tabla ´invoice_detail´ y tampoco mas bien se bloqueo el phpMyAdmin del servidor

Comment: @gbianchi, el fin de la consulta es incluir el la tabla invoice_detail el id del producto y relacionarlo con la tabla products, tambien trate de hacerlo por medio de codigo PHP pero genera error al momento del UPDATE.

Comment: @JuanCarlos si ejecutas una query sencilla para ver cuántos registros habría que cambiar por cada prd_id (SELECT id.idt_productCode,id.idt_productId, pd.prd_code, pd.prd_id
     FROM invoice_detail id JOIN products pd
        ON id.idt_productCode = pd.prd_code
     ORDER BY pr.prd_id
     LIMIT 1) ¿cuántos productos salen? Por qué hacer truncate en una tabla que quieres updatear registros, tras un truncate tendrías que hacer un insert.